# Is there any function to return a relative path from public_html to the file location?

Tags: php

I need a function to return a relative path of the file , every where i run it.
for example this is my code in "loc.php" :

```
<?
echo whereiam();
?>
```

outputs in these directories should be:

```
public_html/loc.php : /
public_html/folder1/folder2/loc.php : ../../
```

Is there any built-in function in php for this use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing you're going to get is:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
?>
```

EDIT: As for the second part of your script, I would probably do something like count the number of '/'s -1 in $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] and echo out that many ../'s? As far as I know there is no function that does something like this out of the box.

Comment: This is absolute but i need relative path

Comment: @AMING this is actually a relative one, but it seems you just have no idea what a relative path is.

Comment: Although I completely agree with Col. Shrapnel, if you wanted something like your original question for whatever reason... I scribbled something up, fully untested:

<?php

whereami();

function whereami() {
  $substr_count = substr_count($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], '/') - 1;
  
  if ($substr_count == 0) {
    echo '/';
  } else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $substr_count; $i++) {
      echo '../';
    }
  }
}
?>

Comment: Thank you , it was so complicated to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant.

```
echo __FILE__;
```

Comment: @AMIN You don't actually need relative

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently **[wrong idea of doing something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**.

There is no point in getting `../../` -style paths out of current location. You can (and should) use an absolute one.

Comment: Thank`s. so i have to use absolute